# Get image dir, name, id from wordpress gallery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am new to wordpress, i am still studying wp and making a plugin. In 1 page of that plugin, i inserted add media button to upload image and i want to get that image directory, name and id for other purposes.

Here is my code:

```
<td>
    <div id="wp-content-media-buttons" class="wp-media-buttons">
        <a href="#" class="button insert-media add_media" data-editor="content" title="Add Media" id="upload-img">
            <span class="wp-media-buttons-icon"></span> Add Image
        </a>
    </div>
    <input id="img_name" class="img_info" name="img_name" type="text" value="Show image name here" /><br/>
    <input id="img_dir" class="img_info" name="img_dir" type="text" value="Show image directory here" /><br/>
    <input id="img_id" class="img_info" name="img_id" type="text" value="Show image id here" />
</td>
```

I want image directory, directory and id show in the input field right after upload/select image. Are there anyway to do that?